# Excel VBA macro script to copy format and values from sheet in template workbook into a new attachment workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template file with the formula based sheets Outlook View and Outlook Summary that compute from data sheets in the template.   All content within these sheets is found in the ranges specified in the respective range codes. I would like to have these sheets copied into a new workbook and saved as a filename found on the template sheet CONTROLS in cell G12.     My problem is I can only get it to work with one of the sheets, and not both.

For example, this works:

```
Sub idpattach()

Dim myWB As New Workbook
Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets("Outlook View").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("CRM Outlook View").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myWB.Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("g12").Value, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Sheets("CONTROLS").Select

End Sub
```

But this doesn't:

```
Sub idpattach()

Dim myWB As New Workbook
Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets("Outlook View").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Outlook Summary").Copy
Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").Copy
Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("CRM Outlook View").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myWB.Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("g12").Value, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Sheets("CONTROLS").Select

End Sub
```

If you could be so kind and please point out my error and show me the correct way to get this working so I don't have to copy the data sheets into the attachment.

Thank you

**EDIT

Got it working like this, but does anyone have any tips on how to do it better?

```
Sub idpattach()

Dim myWB As New Workbook
Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets(Array("Outlook View", "CRM Outlook Summary")).Copy

Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").Copy
Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("CRM Outlook View").Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myWB.Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("g12").Value, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Sheets("CONTROLS").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a code question or a improve request?

Comment: Initially a code question, turned into an improve request.

Comment: "but does anyone have any tips on how to do it better?" Better in which way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be simplified

```
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").Copy
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").Copy
Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

into

```
Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").Copy Destination:= Sheets("Outlook View").Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").Copy Destination:= Sheets("Outlook Summary").Range("a1:q12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

EDIT - The full block can be modified to..

```
Sub idpattach()

Dim myWB As New Workbook
Dim outlookView As Worksheet
Dim outlookSummary As Worksheet

Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set outlookView = Sheets("Outlook View")
Set outlookSummary = Sheets("Outlook Summary")

Sheets(Array("Outlook View", "CRM Outlook Summary")).Copy

outlookView.Range("a1:bm74").Copy Destination:= outlookView.Range("a1:bm74").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
outlookSummary.Range("a1:q12").Copy Destination:= outlookSummary.Range("a1:q12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("CRM Outlook View").Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myWB.Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("g12").Value, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Sheets("CONTROLS").Select

End Sub
```